# Wordpress notification custom field

Tags: wordpress, notifications, advanced-custom-fields

I need to add mail notification on Wordpress.
I've a custom post type with a date custom fields.
When today is the date in custom field for one of the custom post, I need to send mail with all informations from this custom post.
Do you know how I can do this notification ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new function in your WP, in functions.php for example, to scroll through all "custom post type" and compare if the current date is the same as the "custom post type and if so, send the mail (You can use the [php mail function](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php)).
Then you have to talk to your hosting provider and you have to add in cron this function and that you run it every minute.
I hope it helps you, if you need anything else do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! It's ok now.